# How do I get the last part of this filepath?

Tags: c#, io, substring, filepath

I have a filepath that follows the following pattern:

Some\File\Path\Base\yyyy\MM\dd\HH\mm\Random8.3

I want to extract everything from 2012 and beyond, but the problem is that while the right side is standard the base directory can be different for each record.

Here are two examples:

1. C:\Temp\X\2012\08\27\18\35\wy32dm1q.qyt
   Returns: `2012\08\27\18\35\wy32dm1q.qyt`
2. D:\Temp\X\Y\2012\08\27\18\36\tx84uwvr.puq
   Returns: `2012\08\27\18\36\tx84uwvr.puq`

Right now I'm grabbing the `LastIndexOf(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)` N number of times to get the index of the string right before 2012, then getting the substring from that index on. But, I have a feeling that maybe there is a better way?

Comment: I'm withdrawing my answer, I just noticed the "and beyond" in your question. I'd write a function that matches regex "\\\d{4}\\", converts the following 10 characters into a DateTime then compare to 01-01-2012. Unfortunately, I lack expertise with regular expressions and can not provide an authoritative answer.

Comment: Do you have this base directory as a variable in your app?

Comment: You can also use a regex, but why?  Slapping LastIndexOf in a for loop and perhaps wrapping it in its own method is plenty fine.

Comment: @ajay_whiz: it comes from the config file and can change at any time since it is only used to generate the full path (the partial ending path needs to be calculated based on conventions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses regular expressions, assuming the format you're looking for always contains \yyyy\MM\dd\HH\mm.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ExtractPath(@"C:\Temp\X\2012\08\27\18\35\wy32dm1q.qyt"));
        Console.WriteLine(ExtractPath(@"D:\Temp\X\Y\2012\08\27\18\36\tx84uwvr.puq"));
    }

    static string ExtractPath(string fullPath)
    {
        string regexconvention = String.Format(@"\d{{4}}\u{0:X4}(\d{{2}}\u{0:X4}){{4}}\w{{8}}.\w{{3}}", Convert.ToInt32(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        return Regex.Match(fullPath, regexconvention).Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I love the Regex idea, but it returns the initial backslash in front. Any way it can not return that so I can use it in Path.Combine properly?

Comment: of course! I've updated my answer so it doesn't have the leading slash :)

Comment: The Regex should be composed using the `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` since the OP was using that (and because it's the proper way to do things when working with filepaths).

Comment: @jrskillett: I fixed the code. You can't simply concat the `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` inside the string, you need to escape the character just in case it is a special character... however, you can't assume that it is always going to be the backslash character, which means the only true way to escape it (in case it is ANY special character) is to Regex unicode escape it. Though I'm wondering if the character should be converted into an Int32 or UInt32?

Comment: @m-y: I was wondering about that as I was updating the answer, thanks for the tip. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 4):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetLastParts(@"D:\Temp\X\Y\2012\08\27\18\36\tx84uwvr.puq", @"\", 6));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string GetLastParts(string text, string separator, int count)
    {
        string[] parts = text.Split(new string[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        return string.Join(separator, parts.Skip(parts.Count() - count).Take(count).ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: The `Take` is useless. Once you've skipped `parts.Length - count` parts, there's only *count* parts left.

Answer (score 0):

A c# solution would be

```
string str = @"C:\Temp\X\2012\08\27\18\35\wy32dm1q.qyt";
string[] arr=str.Substring(str.IndexOf("2012")).Split(new char[]{'\\'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong w/ your current approach.  It's likely the best for the job.

```
public string GetFilepath(int nth, string needle, string haystack) {
    int lastindex = haystack.Length;

    for (int i=nth; i>=0; i--)
        lastindex = haystack.LastIndexOf(needle, lastindex-1);

    return haystack.Substring(lastindex);
}
```

I'd keep it simple (KISS).  Easier to debug/maintain and probably twice as fast as regex variant.