# Taking the last Substring of a string in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string

```
 "\uploads\test1\test2.file"
```

What's the method to get just "test2.file"?

What I have in my mind is to get the last index of "\" and then perform a string.substring(last index of "\") command on it?

Is there a method that takes just the word after the last "\"?

Comment: you can split the string by '\' charachter and then get last index of array,but the substring is good too

Comment: There is indeed a method that gets the last index of a substring.. it's called.. *drumroll*.. ["LastIndexOf"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Use the method `Path.GetFileName(path);` in `System.IO` namespace, it is much more elegant than doing string operations.

Answer (score 4):

You could use LINQ:

```
var path = @"\uploads\test1\test2.file";

var file = path.Split('\\').Last();
```

You might want to validate the input, if you're concerned about path potentially being `null` or whatnot.

Comment: '\' not ok  ;) '\\' is better,isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
string path = "c:\\inetpub\\wwwrroot\\images\\pdf\\admission.pdf";

string folder = path.Substring(0,path.LastIndexOf(("\\")));
            // this should be "c:\inetpub\wwwrroot\images\pdf"

var fileName = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf(("\\"))+1);
            // this should be admin.pdf
```

For more take a look at here [How do I get the last part of this filepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199600/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Split method:

```
 string myString = "\uploads\test1\test2.file";
 string[] words = myString.Split("\");

 //And take the last element:
 var file = words[words.lenght-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

using linq:

```
"\uploads\test1\test2.file".Split('\\').Last();
```

or you can do it without linq:

```
string[] parts = "\uploads\test1\test2.file".Split('\\');
last_part=parts[parts.length-1]
```